# window.##EventListener not working when returned from a function

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dom-events, conditional-operator

In my code I have multiple functions that use `window.add(remove)EventListener(...)`. I found this trick from a YouTube channel where they used a function to get `document.getElementById` instead of writing a bunch of times. But its not working, I tried something like this:

```
function addListen(x, y) {
   return window.addEventListener(x, y);
}
```

Then maybe call it like this:

```
...addListen("scroll", funcName)..
```

To be specific I was calling it from a ternary operator: `i == # ? addListen(x, y):...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My simple example does work (http://jsfiddle.net/NameFILIP/ohxjarnq/2/):

```
function addListen(x, y) {
  return window.addEventListener(x, y);
}
function doNothing() {}
var i = 3;
i === 3 ? addListen("click", function () { 
  alert('clicked');   
}) : doNothing();
```

Maybe something went wrong with your ternary operator? Check has the `addListen` function  been executed? Take into account that it's recommended to always use ===.

You can also use a [Visual Event](http://sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2) trick to inspect your event listeners.